# MongoDB Golang UpdateOne array

Tags: mongodb, go

I made a method `UpdateMessage` to update the message, I can only update a few fields: `message.body`, `message.update_at` and `message.modifications array`

Below I attached a method that I wrote, I do NOT get an error, none at all, but the data are not updated, if I make a query to the database and check after calling this method, the data will not change.

**What am I doing wrong when trying to update a database record?**

Is there anything I can do to simplify the `ChangeMessage` method, namely to get rid of passing the old message to the new one by parameters? I need each message to keep the old version of the message in the `message.modifications` field if the data changes?

```golang
type Message struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    ChatID     string `json:"chat_id" bson:"chat_id"`
    FromID     string `json:"from_id" bson:"from_id"`
    CreateDate int64  `json:"create_date" bson:"create_date"`
    Type string `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Media    string `json:"media" bson:"media"`
    Body     string `json:"body" bson:"body"`
    UpdateAt int64  `json:"update_at" bson:"update_at"`
    Modifications []*Message `json:"modifications,omitempty" bson:"modifications"`
    Viewed        bool       `json:"viewed" bson:"viewed"`
}
```

```golang
func (srv *Service) ChangeMessage(ctx context.Context, message *Message) error {
    ...
    chat, err := srv.db.Chat.Find(ctx, &Chat{ID: message.ChatID})


    msg, err := srv.db.Chat.FindMessage(ctx, &Message{
        ID:     message.ID,
        ChatID: chat.ID,
        FromID: uid,
    })
    ....

    message.Modifications = msg.Modifications
    message.Modifications = append(message.Modifications, msg)
    message.FromID = msg.FromID
    message.CreateDate = msg.CreateDate
    message.Type = msg.Type
    message.Media = msg.Media
    message.ChatID = msg.ChatID
    message.Viewed = msg.Viewed

    err = srv.db.Chat.UpdateMessage(ctx, message)
    
    .......
}
```

```golang
func (m *Mongo) UpdateMessage(ctx context.Context, msg *Message) error {
    ...
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "body":      msg.Body,
            "update_at": time.Now().UnixMilli(),
        },
        "$push": bson.M{
            "modifications": msg.Modifications,
        },
    }

    _, err := m.col.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"id": msg.ID}, update, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help here. I put together a small example to show you how to deal with your scenario (at least for the updating issue):

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var (
    ctx    context.Context
    cancel context.CancelFunc
)

type Message struct {
    ID   string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // set MongoDB connection
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)

    // select collection
    collection := mongoClient.Database("demodb").Collection("myCollection")
    defer collection.Drop(ctx)

    fmt.Println("original documents")
    // insert some random msg
    if _, err := collection.InsertMany(ctx, []interface{}{
        Message{"1", "John Doe"},
        Message{"2", "Suzy Lee"},
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // get records
    var messagesTmp []bson.M
    cursorTmp, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cursorTmp.All(ctx, &messagesTmp); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range messagesTmp {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("#", 100))

    // update
    var updateRes *mongo.UpdateResult
    if updateRes, err = collection.UpdateOne(ctx,
        bson.M{"name": "John Doe"},
        bson.D{
            bson.E{
                Key: "$set",
                Value: bson.D{
                    bson.E{
                        Key:   "name",
                        Value: "John Doe - Edited",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("num docs updated:", updateRes.ModifiedCount)

    // list all
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("#", 100))
    fmt.Println("new documents")
    var messages []Message
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cursor.All(ctx, &messages); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range messages {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

With this code, you should be able to successfully update your documents in MongoDB. To give it a try, make sure to run MongoDB at the right address with the credentials expected in the code.

About the document versioning, I think that you're already following a kind of *Document Versioning Pattern*. You can find more about it at this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern).

Let me know if this clarifies your doubts or if you need something else, thanks!